# Force outputLink redirect

Tags: apex, jquery

I want to dynamically reset the 'value' attribute of of this outputLink.

```
        <div class="BackLink">
            <apex:outputLink target="_top" value="/apex/ThisPage" styleClass="backlink" >This page</apex:outputLink>
        </div>
```

So maybe?

```
        <div class="BackLink">
            <apex:outputLink onclick="redirect('/apex/AnotherPage')" target="_top" value="/apex/ThisPage" styleClass="backlink" >This page</apex:outputLink>
        </div>


        function redirect(value){
            (sforce.one.navigateToURL(value));

        }
```

This doesnt work but I'm unsure how to proceed. 
Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to evaluate the value at page load time or when a user clicks the link?

Comment: You can create a getter setter property and then on action call as per your business logic you can change in controller.Use merge field for dynamic population

Comment: @Bar, I don't really mind. My first instinct was to do it onclick.

Comment: I would ten to agree with @Mohith.  I would use an property in the controller to set eh value of the output link

Comment: Looks like @BarCotter answered similarly.  That is the approach I would take as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its possible to work out the URL when the page loads then you could do something like this:

```
<apex:outputLink target="_top" value="{!backLinkUrl}" styleClass="backlink" >This page</apex:outputLink>
```

And the controller would be:

```
public String backLinkUrl {
    get {
        if (something) {
            backLinkUrl = 'http://google.com';
        } else {
            backLinkUrl = 'http://bing.com';
        }
        return backLinkUrl;
    }
    private set;
}
```

If you want to evaluate the URL when a user clicks the link then you could use a commandLink:

```
<apex:commandLink value="This page" action="{!backLinkAction}"/>
```

The controller would be:

```
public PageReference backLinkAction() {
    if (something) {
        return Page.ThisPage;
    } else {
        return Page.ThisOtherPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: took some messing around (because I didnt explain my problem as well as I could have) but works like a charm, cheers Bar!